# Mid-2000's mini-series: Secret facility containing psychically-gifted children

Tags: story-identification, tv, psychic, telekinesis

The following list is all the elements I can remember from this series:

1)  It was a mini-series of about 4 to 6 episodes each lasting about 45 minutes to an hour.

2)  It was made either in America or Canada somewhere between 2001 and 2005 (I watched it in South Africa somewhere between 2002 and 2006)

3)  The story was about a secret facility that contained and studied children with psychic abilities.

4)  There was a particularly strong child who could control people's actions, but only one person at a time.

5)  I remember a scene where someone new to the facility was walking from cell to cell seeing the different children, one of whom was drawing a picture by controlling the crayons with her mind.

6)  The primary conflict was about one child who was secreted out of the facility and is being pursued by a grizzled military type guy (who may or may not have had a cigar) who was in charge of the facility's security.

That is all I can recall at the moment but I welcome any questions for clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bears a considerable resemblance to *[Firestarter: Rekindled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firestarter:_Rekindled)*.  In this 2002 mini-series sequel to the 1984 movie adaptation, Charlie (the titular girl) is grown up and working in a library when Rainbird resurfaces with a collection of six boys with different powers -- one of which has the power of suggestion (similar to Charlie's father, but more powerful and less self-harmful), two of which are telkinetic (which would be the ability to draw without touching the crayons), and the others have other powers.

Rainbird is using them to commit crimes, and Charlie has to find a way to rescue them -- one guess what way that will be...

Comment: Bingo.  I got some of the elements wrong, but to be fair it was a decade and a half ago.  But regardless, you got it right.  This is indeed what I saw all those years ago.  Many thanks.